# Errors installing cordova on windows 10

Tags: cordova, npm, installation

I would like to install the latest stable version of cordova on my development machine.

But the installation failed and gave a warning on minimatch needing an update. So I updated to npm v3, which installed 3.10.6. Now I am getting a different error, but still the warning about minimatch aswell. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Is npm v3 the latest stable release or have I managed to install a beta version?

I tried the clean command on both npm and cordova and I am running the console as administrator

```
$ npm install -g cordova
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
C:\Users\Acuity\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Acuity\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Acuity\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-a6a00b47
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Acuity\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-a6a00b47' -> 'C:\Users\Acuity\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Acuity\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-a6a00b47' -> 'C:\Users\Acuity\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Acuity\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled all node modules and nodejs and started with a blank environment, now it works